# Safely call Arc::from_raw multiple times for a raw pointer? In other words, how to hold a raw pointer of an Arc and later use it multiple times?

Tags: rust

I [need to](https://github.com/fzyzcjy/flutter_rust_bridge/pull/293) hold a raw pointer of an Arc, and later use it multiple times. Then, is it safe to do the following?

```
use std::sync::Arc;

let x_ptr = Arc::into_raw(Arc::new(some_big_object));

// Use it concurrently and multiple times.
// Ignore the grammar error since this is only a demonstration.
for i in 0..10 {
  thread::spawn(|| {
    unsafe {
      let x_recovered = ManuallyDrop::new(Arc::from_raw(x_ptr));
      let x_recovered_cloned = x_recovered.clone();
      make_use_of_it(x_recovered);
    }
  });
}

wait_and_join_the_threads();

// Here I really deallocate the memory.
drop(Arc::from_raw(x_ptr));

fn make_use_of_it(x: Arc) {...}
```

Comment: Why the `ManuallyDrop`?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman avoid double free

Comment: Then why is the clone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Arc::increment_strong_count()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/sync/struct.Arc.html#method.increment_strong_count):

```rust
let x_ptr = Arc::into_raw(Arc::new(some_big_object));

for i in 0..10 {
    thread::spawn(|| {
        unsafe {
            Arc::increment_strong_count(x_ptr);
            let x_recovered = Arc::from_raw(x_ptr);
            make_use_of_it(x_recovered);
        }
    });
}

unsafe {
    Arc::decrement_strong_count(x_ptr);
    // Could be also
    // drop(Arc::from_raw(x_ptr));
}
```

Comment: Then if an error happens *between* increment_strong_count and from_raw we are in trouble?

Comment: You'll have a memory leak (not much trouble when an error occurs, usually). But why won't you just put the `increment_strong_count()` immediately before the `from_raw()`, so no error can occur in between?

Comment: Sure I will put immediately before. Just wondering whether will panic?

Comment: They cannot panic (`increment_strong_count()`, though, can abort if the refcounter overflows).